# Turning down the sound on a switched off user

Tags: windows-7, audio, fast-user-switching

If one switches users (i.e. user one switches off, and then another users logs in) and there is sound playing on the first user, that sound will continue to play for the second user.

If the second user has admin rights, they can guess what program is causing the sound and then  kill it, but that is very clumsy, and far more than what "needs" to be done.

When I open the mixer, it just shows that sound is playing. How can I stop it?

Comment: thought, before departing the other user a script that adjusts the all application sounds down, or stops or taskends specific applications?  log-off script?

Comment: It is not a log off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this is not possible. For more information see [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-sound/how-to-mute-user-that-is-left-on-the-background/8d4ed0bd-44f6-4698-9524-0a2676b2eb71?auth=1).

Answer (score 3):

Just like processes from other users won't be shown (by default) when running task manager (taskmgr.exe) without elevated privileges... You need to run the volume mixer (**sndvol.exe**) as an administrator to view programs making sounds from other users.

Go to the start menu, type in **sndvol**; when you see it, right click on it; click **run as administrator** and click allow when the security box pops up, depending on your config.

[Apologies for the low quality post. I will clean up my grammar, and add pictures in a little while, just wanted to get you an answer ASAP.]

Comment: Does not work...

Comment: OK... try [MonitorES](http://code.google.com/p/monitores/)

Comment: what does that have to do with anything? I am not turning off my monitor.

Comment: It lists "Mute master sound.( XP,Vista,7).  " in it's features